# Do any of the unlocks modify the sniper's mortar strike?

Tags: battlefield-bad-company-2

The sniper's mortar strike is a favorite of mine, and I was wondering if any of the unlocks upgrade it.  For instance, there are unlocks for more missiles, ammo, or grenades.

Are there any that reduce the cooldown time, give you a second mortar strike, or increase the damage/size of the mortar strike?

Comment: I asked this question on the Bad Company 2 forum here http://forum.ea.com/eaforum/posts/list/0/4704231.page#11706804 . They seem to think that 'improved demolitions' does effect the mortar strike because it's listed when you die.  Also the sniper's binoculars are effected by 12x zoom, even though it is not explicitly mentioned in the perk description.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am pretty sure demolition spec improves mortar strike damage by 25% as well.

Comment: I thought also and checked before posting but from this page (http://www.joinaclan.com/2010/06/bfbc2-battlefield-bad-company-2-magnum-ammo-and-improved-demolitions/) it seems not the be the case for the mortar (unfortunately)

Comment: @LudoMC, Your probably right based on your link, but I hope you don't mind if I wait to see if people vote one or another up?

Comment: No problem of course, that's the game and I will be "happy" to be wrong and be able to crush enemies with devastating mortar strikes also :))

Comment: @LudoMC They just don't mention mortar strike there, as they don't mention C4 and mines, but it works on those two 100%.

Comment: @serg Don't see it either here (http://battlefield.wikia.com/wiki/Improved_Demolitions). Do you have a link or something? I'm very interested also in this.

Comment: @LudoMC Don't have any links, but I remember others mentioning it on forums, and it complies with my experience (though it is hard to tell for sure, mortar strike is random by design so you never know).

Comment: @LudoMC: wikia says "Improved Demolitions are coupled to the player, not the weapon."

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately no. I always found my enemies' mortar strike more deadly than mine. The solution is in precise targeting. Once unlocked, there is no upgrade of it. The only thing which is upgraded for Recon class is the scope.

As a bonus, seeing your other questions on BFBC2, don't forget also to mark the enemies when you see them in your scope (same as calling a medic, calling for ammo, etc...). They will then appear in your colleagues' map for a short amount of time.

Answer (score 1):

Per the comment on the Q:

> They seem to think that 'improved demolitions' does effect the mortar strike because it's listed when you die.

I agree; one of the on-screen tips when you die is basically

> Improved demolitons improves the effect of all explosives, including the sniper mortar strike

I'm 100% sure it called out mortar strike *specifically* in that message. I've sure seen it enough (cough).